# Codeigniter SQL query : i want to retrieve data from one table using the data from other table

Tags: sql, codeigniter

i am a beginner in codeigniter , im having a trouble with my query , i want to retrieve all data from one table where i will use the data of another table .for example is i have a orderlogs table and i want to retrieve all of the data of orderlogs table where it will match the logged in username. so what i want to do specifically was each user can view specifically the transanction history they made  . im making a reservation system  . this is my model code :

ITEM MODEL  query :

```
public function getUserslog($username){
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('orderlogs');
    $this->db->join('users','users.username=orderlogs.username');
    $this->db->where('orderlogs.username',$username); 
    $q = $this->db->get();

    return $q->result();
}
```

Controller code :

```
public function itemuserlogs() {
    $check_session = $this->session->userdata('login');

    if (!isset($check_session)) {
        redirect('login/index','refresh');
    }

    $this->pagi_orders();

    $username = $this->session->userdata('username');
    $user['user'] = $this->UserModel->userdata($username);
    $this->load->view('layout/header_user', $user);
    $this->load->model('ItemModel');
    $data['items'] = $this->ItemModel->getUserslog(5, $this->uri->segment(3));
    $data['page'] = $this->uri->segment(3);
    $msg = $this->session->userdata('msg');

    if (isset($msg)) {
        $data['msg'] = $msg;
    }

    $item_id = $this->session->userdata('item_id');

    if (isset($item_id)) {
        $this->session->unset_userdata('item_id');
    }

    $this->load->view('item/item_logs_view', $data);
}
```

hope you could help thanks .

Comment: You are passing two parameters to getUserslog function and receiving only one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

$this->ItemModel->getUserslog(5, $this->uri->segment(3));

To

$this->ItemModel->getUserslog($username);

Comment: any help how i can specify my pagination rows now .

Answer (score 1):

As checked on your code. I think you should be providing the username to your Model method

Change

```
$this->ItemModel->getUserslog(5, $this->uri->segment(3));
```

To

```
$this->ItemModel->getUserslog($username);
```

Comment: hey Thanks man it works !  i was getting confused with that code cause i thought it was for my pagination.

Comment: No worries buddy :D

Comment: now my problem is i cant determine how many rows is for my pagination

Comment: you should make another question for that